# TSP using genetic algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

How do I implement 'insert mutation' and 'cycle recombination' for a TSP problem using genetic algorithm in Python3?

Assume I have done the selection steps and now I have two parents for reproduction.

This is what I have done so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Dec 13 14:15:31 2016

@author: niloo
"""

import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
from geopy.distance import great_circle as gcy


    def read(file_name):
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_name, sep="  ")
        data = np.array(data)
        return data


    def Dist(data):
        # distance = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            temp = []
            for j in range(len(data)):
                if j < i:
                    temp.append(distance[j][i])
                elif i == j:
                    temp.append(0)
                else:
                    temp.append(gcy((data[i][0], data[i][1]), (data[j][0], data[j][1])).km)
            distance.append(temp)
        #print(distance[1][2])
        return distance


    def k_fitness():
        k = 50
        t = 3
        first_gener = []
        how_fit = []
        for i in range(0, k):
            temp = np.random.permutation(535)
            first_gener.append(temp)
        for i in range(len(first_gener)):
            sum_dis = 0
            for j in range(0, 534):
                temp1 = first_gener[i][j]
                temp2 = first_gener[i][j + 1]
                sum_dis += distance[int(temp1)][int(temp2)]
            how_fit.append(sum_dis)
        # print(how_fit)
        race1 = np.random.randint(k, size=t)
        winner1 = 9999999999999999999
        for i in range(0, t):
            if how_fit[int(race1[i])] < winner1:
                winner1 = how_fit[int(race1[i])]
                mom = first_gener[int(race1[i])]
                #print (mom)
        race2 = np.random.randint(k, size=t)
        winner2 = 9999999999999999999
        for i in range(0, t):
            if how_fit[int(race2[i])] < winner2:
                winner2 = how_fit[int(race2[i])]
                dad = first_gener[int(race2[i])]
        return mom, dad


    def cross_over(mom , dad):
        #mom = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        #dad = [9,3,7,8,2,6,5,1,4]
        if len(mom) != len(dad):
            print ('error')
        else:
            child1 = [0] * len(mom)
            child2 = [0] * len(mom)
            flag = False
            index = [0] * len(mom)
            while True:
                ind = -1
                for i in range(len(mom)):
                    if index[i] == 0:
                        ind = i
                        break
                if ind == -1:
                    break
                temp = ind

                while True:
                    index[temp] = 1
                    if flag == False:
                        child1[temp] = mom[temp]
                        child2[temp] = dad[temp]

                    else:
                        child1[temp] = dad[temp]
                        child2[temp] = mom[temp]

                    val = dad[temp]
                    for i in range(len(dad)):
                        if mom[i] == val:
                            temp = i
                            break
                    if ind == temp:
                        break
                if flag == False:
                    flag = True
                else:
                    flag = False

            #print child1
            #print child2

            return [child1 , child2]


    def mutation(offspring):
        if random.random() <= 0.02:
            index1 = random.randint(534)
            index2 = random.randint(534)
            if index1 != index2:
                ind1 = min(index1 , index2)
                ind2 = max(index1 , index2)
                temp = offspring [ : ind1+1]
                temp += offspring [ind2 : ind2+1]
                temp += offspring [ind1+1 : ind2]
                temp += offspring [ind2+1 : ]
                offspring = temp
            return offspring
        else:
            return offspring



    dat = read('ali535.tsp')
    distance = []
    Dist(dat)
    k_fitness()
```

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like homework. And I would think the fact that this is for a TSP is irrelevant. Have you looked up how to do insert mutations and cycle combinations? Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: It's not irrelevant if the mutation operator inserts repeated values into the chromosome. A solution isn't valid if a city is visited twice. As for OP, check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting. This will help gather you good answers.

Comment: @NoahBogart If it's an invalid solution though, couldn't you just give it a low score and let it get "naturally" killed off?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah, you could, but that will slow the search down. If some non-zero number of your chromosomes have "negative infinity" fitness, they're not actually contributing to the search. Why not write crossover and mutation operators that generate valid chromosomes?

Comment: @NoahBogart I guess. I was thinking it would be better to have a general GA that isn't tied to a specific problem, but I suppose speed is a factor, and the use of the operators could be abstracted behind an interface so different ones can be plugged in. I've written GAs before, but never used them for anything practical. Was just curious what your reasoning was. Thanks.